# How to create a pdf file from a Listview or Recyclerview in java?

Tags: java, pdf

Please help me, How to create PDF file from a Listview or Recyclerview in Java.

```
private void convertXMLtoPDF() {
        //Inflate the Layout
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_purchase_item_plate,null);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
            this.getDisplay().getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
        } else this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(displayMetrics.widthPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(displayMetrics.heightPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

        view.layout(3,6, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

        int viewWidth = view.getMeasuredWidth();
        int viewHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();

        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(viewWidth, viewHeight, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        //Canvas
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        view.draw(canvas);

   
        document.finishPage(page);



        File createFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        String folderName = "GEO STOCK";

        File myDir = new File(createFolder + "/" + folderName);
        myDir.mkdirs();

        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fileName = "XML-"+ n +".pdf";
        File file = new File(myDir, fileName);


        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            document.writeTo(fos);
            document.close();
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Create XML to PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("mylog", "Error while writing"+ e.toString());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```